# Basic DB connection pool with Java and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I'm trying to create my first connection pool. I'm creating a Java web aplication with Tomcat 7 and a MySQL DB, and I'd like to create the simplest connection pool possible.
I've taken a look at several tutorials but it's not really clear for me, so I'd like you to confirm if I'm doing well.

I've written the following class as a connection pool manager:

```
package dao.mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

public class MySQLConnectionPool {

    private static DataSource datasource;
    private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    private static String username = "user";
    private static String password = "password";

    public MySQLConnectionPool() {
        datasource = new DataSource(configurePoolProperties(driver, url, username, password));
    }

    private PoolProperties configurePoolProperties(String driver, String url, String username, String password) {
        PoolProperties properties = new PoolProperties();
        properties.setDriverClassName(driver);
        properties.setUrl(url);
        properties.setUsername(username);
        properties.setPassword(password);
        return properties;
    } 

    public static synchronized Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = datasource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while getting a connection from the pool! \nSQL state:" + ex.getSQLState() + "\nMESSAGE" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the **static** properties nor the **synchronized**.

And I'm not sure about the "client" classes of the pool. I understand they have only to get a connection using

```
Connection con = MySQLConnectionPool.getConnection();
```

and finally close this connection using

```
con.close();
```

And that's it?
And also, is there any simpler or better way to do this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the wrong way to do it.

Tomcat already has a connection pool and you can configure and setup without any code through the `context.xml` in the `conf` directory.

Once it is defined there, all you need to do is to lookup the JNDI DataSource in your code. Hardcoding all that (and re-inventing the wheel) is a very bad idea.

To learn how to configure a JNDI DataSource check out the manual: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

The Tomcat manual also has an example on how to obtain a connection from the pool:

```
InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/dsname" );
```

where `dsname` is the name you provided in the `context.xml`

Comment: A DAO does not *manage* a DataSource, it simply *uses* it. You might also want to read the JavaEE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjj.html

Comment: If the connection pool is configurated as JNDI DataSource in Tomcat and the factory attribute of the Resource is  `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`, what is the DataSource type when accessing the datasource from a class java? I use `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`, or it should be `javax.sql.DataSource` (the latter is the value of the `type` attribute of the Resource)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) and the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) Tomcat documentation. Letting Tomcat do it is preferable especially since it avoids class loader leaks.