# Which DataSource for application used both in standalone and webapp context (Java 7, Tomcat 7)?

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, jndi, desktop-application

I build an application which has a standalone "core" layer, that is also used to build a webapp (it is a Maven multi-module project, with a 'core' module, and a 'webapp' module, that has a dependency to the 'core' module). 
It uses a MySQL database. I try to implement a `DataSource` that would be fine in both contexts (only 1 connection is enough in the standalone context).

After reading a lot of documentations about DataSources, I have to say that I am a bit lost. I came to the conclusion that maybe I should use the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). My questions are:

1) in the standalone context, how should I provide the configuration to use the DataSource, knowing that this configuration will be provided by Tomcat in the webapp context (the standalone config should thus not override the Tomcat config)?

- Should I do something like [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792469/basic-db-connection-pool-with-java-and-tomcat-7) in a method called only in the standalone context? But how can I see in the webapp context that Tomcat has already provided the DataSource?
- Or Should I rather use a bean definition? But how this bean would not be used in the webapp context?

2) What about other pooled DataSource implementations?

- Shouldn't I just use the [MySQL DataSource](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)?
- I read that in Java EE 7, DataSources are simpler to use (https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/default_datasource_in_java_ee). So, is there any breakthrough in Java 7? A new DataSource provider that I should absolutely use in Java 7?

Conclusion: 
Yep, I'm lost, and I don't know what are the "gold standards" for DataSource usage. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lookup the DataSource in the core module. You need create the [JNDI Datasource in Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/) for the webapp module and the [Standalone JNDI support](http://penguindreams.org/blog/running-beans-that-use-application-server-datasources-locally/) for standalone module.

e.g. For getting the `Connection` from datasource is the same in both context:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

But the configuration of datasource is diferent. In Tomcat you will see something like that in the examples in the links.

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/MySQLDB" ... />
</Context>
```

The name of resource in the standalone must be she same like the `ctx.lookup` call in standalone:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB", ds1);
```

The `InitialContextFactory` in the standalone module must be created independently of core module.

About the `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353593/870248). Tomcat uses the Apache Software Foundation's DBCP libraries, which you can also use in your own non-Java EE code: http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dbcp/

For JDBC Connection Pool in Tomcat see [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) and for Apache DBCP Pool see [this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?view=markup).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a few questions then: my 'core' layer is a library that can be used in other applications. If I don't want these applications to perform the tasks described in your second link, the InitialContext should be set **inside** the core layer, right? So maybe I should more simply perform the lookup in the core layer, catch the exception thrown if not in a webapp context, then set my own Connection in that case? Would that be valid?

Comment: If the 'core' contains such functionality, that could be executed by other applications. You could generate a third component (with the custom `InitialContextFactory` )  that could be called from standalone application. I think that this requirement  functionality may be unique to the standalone application, so you could embed it in such an application. In another hand, you could implement a connection factory.

Comment: Yep, just a simple connection factory using a DriverManager, when the DataSource cannot be loaded using JNDI. The Driver could be configured through a property file. Would that be valid? Os is it a terrible design pattern? :p